# Custom reflection functionality in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, architecture

Is it possible to override reflection functionality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what way? What you can do is override the ComponentModel functionality, allowing your object to expose different properties at runtime than it does at compile - but this doesn't change reflection. This approach is used to support data-binding of (for example) `DataView`. You would look at `ICustomTypeDescriptor`.

In .NET 4.0 dynamic objects arrive; there is no special C# support for **authoring** a dynamic object, but if you don't mind doing the legwork you can write an object that behaves for non-static callers.

But to echo "silky" - what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Changing properties at runtime would be enough, I consider this an answer ... thank you.

Note: sometimes I ask the question in generic/fuzzy way cause I don.t need a specific answer... sharing thoughts.